# Geometry Nodes: is it possible to put a curve to connect in vertices of a grid or any other mesh? for a graph

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a graph and I want to make it procedural in some way, I want to be able to put a curve connect in between different verts so when the graph gets bigger so does the curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

UPDATE:

you can always move "things" in GN with the transform node:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this but is there a way to make the curve to move?

Comment: please elaborate how the curve should move? you didn't write anything of this in your question. Of course it can move - just append a transform node at the end. But i guess you want something different? And if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer. thank you. If you have additional/other questions, please open a new question because you should only ask one question (these are the rules, i didn't make the rules...)

Comment: oh well I wanted to just know how to make the curve move on the x-axis so it looks like a radio or smt similar, but if I'm breaking the rules by asking twice then just ignore it

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for helping me out I was going mad cheers

Comment: glad you made it. You are welcome.